# Web server URL lost when submitting a form in spring application

Tags: spring, web

I am using a sample spring web application and hosting it on the cloud. I am displaying a form to input some values to the application. When I submit the form using the submit button, the page is directed to /Myapp/createform.htm. What I expect is the form is submitted to my webserver ec2-url/Myapp/createform.htm . The web url is lost and the submission of the form tries to find a website by name Myapp/createform.htm. Please let me know what might be wrong. Also let me know if the information provided is sufficient. I am very much new to this. Also this code works well on the local host.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title><spring:message code="title.create" /></title>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include flush="true" page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
     <div align="left"><spring:message code="${message}" text="" /></div>
     <!-- Album Creation Form -->
     <form:form>
<form:errors path="*" />
<table id="createAlbum">
    <tr>
        <th>Album Name*</th>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <td><form:textarea path="description" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Album Labels</th>
        <td><c:forEach items="${labels}" var="label">
            <form:checkbox path="labels" value="${label}" />${label}   <br />
        </c:forEach></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Creation Date</th>
        <td><form:input path="creationDate" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
   </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is not submitting to the correct location, you should try specifying the target URL in the form definition:

```
<form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createform.htm">
```

Or use whatever URL that your target controller will pick up on.  It's better to not assume that the target URL is the correct one and specify it instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Followed what you said with additional stuff as follows to get the entire URL.                                                                    action="http://{pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}      ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createform.htm"